# iphone UIbutton with image click problem

Tags: iphone, image, uibutton

I have 3 UIbuttons in my with background image in my app...

for all those 3 buttons if images are assigned only lower half portion of button is clickable and upper half doesn't work at all..

any idea why ?

I tried to put color for buttons to check if they have right CGRect but it looks proper...

Here is some code

```
    UIButton* segment=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0+(i* segmentWidth) , 0,segmentWidth, 34)];

    segment.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentActionButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [segment setTag:i];

    segment.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0];

    segment.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    [segment setTitle:[mItems objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [segment setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        [segment setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:SEGMENT_IMAGE_INACTIVE_MAP] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [segment setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:SEGMENT_IMAGE_ACTIVE_MAP] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


    [self addSubview:segment];
    [mButtonArray addObject:segment];
    [segment release];
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: showing the code would be helpful to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Are you using IB to set them in your window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the error occurs because you are creating button in `alloc+initWithFrame` way. I'm not sure but try to create button in such way:

```
UIButton* segment = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
segment.frame = CGRectMake(0+(i* segmentWidth) , 0,segmentWidth, 34);
```

And remove line `[segment release];` as you will create `autoreleased` object.

Comment: tried but still doesn't work...i mean only lower half works..upper half still not click able...